# increment of value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i need to increment value in xslt based on attribute. suppose my xml like this,

```
   <comp>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-001"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-002"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-003"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-004" resumeatnum="7"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-005"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-006"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-007" resumeatnum="18"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-008"/>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-009"/>
   </comp>
```

i need output like this,

```
<comp>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-001"/>
<fignum>1.1</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-002"/>
<fignum>1.2</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-003"/>
<fignum>1.3</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-004" resumeatnum="7"/>
<fignum>1.7</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-005"/>
<fignum>1.8</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-006"/>
<fignum>1.9</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-007" resumeatnum="18"/>
<fignum>1.18</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-008"/>
<fignum>1.19</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-009"/>
<fignum>1.20</fignum>
</comp>
```

i need to take values from attribute `xml:id` like `1` from `c1` and another number from the number that's come after `fig`.

if there's a attribute `resumeatnum` then i need to use that value instead of the normal value and increment the value for the following node. please provide the xslt to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate approach is to start off by just matching the first **fig** element

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="fig[1]"/>
```

Then you have a main template to match **fig** elements, but with a parameter that will hold the 'incrementing' value. Notice it also acts as a named template.

```
<xsl:template match="fig" name="fig">
   <xsl:param name="sequence" select="1"/>
```

Within this you can output your **fignum** elements

```
<fignum>
   <xsl:value-of 
      select="concat(substring-before(substring(@xml:id, 2, string-length(@xml:id) - 1), '-'), '.', $sequence)"/>
</fignum>
```

Then you would match the next **fig** element, incrementing the value of the parameter

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::fig[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="sequence" select="$sequence + 1"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
```

To reset the sequence, you just have a template matching **fig** elements which have the relevant attributes, and you can just call the named-template with the attribute value to override it

```
<xsl:template match="fig[@resumeatnum != '']">
   <xsl:call-template name="fig">
      <xsl:with-param name="sequence" select="@resumeatnum"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="comp">
      <comp>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="fig[1]"/>
      </comp>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="fig[@resumeatnum != '']">
      <xsl:call-template name="fig">
         <xsl:with-param name="sequence" select="@resumeatnum"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="fig" name="fig">
      <xsl:param name="sequence" select="1"/>
      <fig>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <fignum>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(substring(@xml:id, 2, string-length(@xml:id) - 1), '-'), '.', $sequence)"/>
         </fignum>
      </fig>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::fig[1]">
         <xsl:with-param name="sequence" select="$sequence + 1"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<comp>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-001">
      <fignum>1.1</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-002">
      <fignum>1.2</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-003">
      <fignum>1.3</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-004" resumeatnum="7">
      <fignum>1.7</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-005">
      <fignum>1.8</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-006">
      <fignum>1.9</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-007" resumeatnum="18">
      <fignum>1.18</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-008">
      <fignum>1.19</fignum>
   </fig>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-009">
      <fignum>1.20</fignum>
   </fig>
</comp>
```

Comment: is this possible without using match `comp` that's only using match `fig` and `fig[@resumeatnum != ''] `?

Comment: Yes, change the template match to `<xsl:template match="comp[not(*[not(self::fig) or @resumeatnum = ''])]">`. You will probably need another template for `<xsl:template match="comp">` to pick up the other cases too.

Comment: please see my edited question. it's not having any root node. now how to write xslt for this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with editing questions if it adds more information, fixes a mistake or clarifies an issue. But be careful in making a change that alters the whole context of the question, especially after people have answered. In this case, removing the comp element means your XML is no longer valid. XML elements need a root element!

Answer (score 1):

The following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="comp">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="fig" group-starting-with="*[@resumeatnum]">
      <xsl:variable name="base" select="(@resumeatnum, 1)[1] - 1"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <fignum>1.<xsl:value-of select="position()+$base"/></fignum>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-001"/>
<fignum>1.1</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-002"/>
<fignum>1.2</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-003"/>
<fignum>1.3</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-004" resumeatnum="7"/>
<fignum>1.7</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-005"/>
<fignum>1.8</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-006"/>
<fignum>1.9</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-007" resumeatnum="18"/>
<fignum>1.18</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-008"/>
<fignum>1.19</fignum>
<fig xml:id="c1-fig-009"/>
<fignum>1.20</fignum>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a shorter (33 well-formatted short lines) and simpler XSLT 1.0 solution (three short templates, no `substring()`, no `substring-before()`, no complicated and long, multiline expressions, no `concat()`, no `xsl:for-each`, no `xsl:if`, no `xsl:variable`, no `string-length()`, no `xsl:call-template`**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="fig[not(@resumeatnum)]"
      use="generate-id((preceding-sibling::*[@resumeatnum][1]
                      |
                        ..
                        )[last()]
                      )"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <comp>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="fig[@resumeatnum]"/>
  </comp>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fig">
  <xsl:param name="pStart" select="1"/>

  <fig xml:id="{@xml:id}"/>
   <fignum>1.<xsl:value-of select="position() + $pStart -1"/></fignum>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fig[@resumeatnum]">
   <fig xml:id="{@xml:id}" resumeatnum="{@resumeatnum}"/>
   <fignum>1.<xsl:value-of select="@resumeatnum"/></fignum>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())">
   <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="@resumeatnum+1"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<comp>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-001"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-002"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-003"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-004" resumeatnum="7"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-005"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-006"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-007" resumeatnum="18"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-008"/>
    <fig xml:id="c1-fig-009"/>
</comp>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<comp>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-001"/>
   <fignum>1.1</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-002"/>
   <fignum>1.2</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-003"/>
   <fignum>1.3</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-004" resumeatnum="7"/>
   <fignum>1.7</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-005"/>
   <fignum>1.8</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-006"/>
   <fignum>1.9</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-007" resumeatnum="18"/>
   <fignum>1.18</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-008"/>
   <fignum>1.19</fignum>
   <fig xml:id="c1-fig-009"/>
   <fignum>1.20</fignum>
</comp>
```

Comment: is this possible without using match `comp` that's only using match `fig` and `fig[@resumeatnum != ''] `?

Comment: What do you mean? `comp` is not matched at all in this transformation. It is only *generated* as it is required to be in the result as per this problem. Of course, if it wasn't required, it is trivial not to generate it and the transfotmation would be slightly shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
<xsl:for-each select="/comp/fig">
    <fignum>1.<xsl:value-of select="substring(@xml:id,string-length(@xml:id),1)"/>1</fignum>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Haven't used xslt/xpath for a while so might not be perfect. Basically just loops through the fig nodes and substrings the last character. If you're going to have more than 9 nodes to loop through you'll have to change the substring to get all the digits

Answer (score 0):

PigChicken, I think he was asking for something to have a modifying auto-increment feature based on the previous [if existing] resumeatnum attribute. The following works perfectly for the given example by creating variables for the major and minor version components, then adding in a "offset" from the resume to it's corresponding minor version. For example, a resumeatnum of 18 with the minor version of 7 gives an offset of 11, which is added to the following minor versions as well. I made use of the number() cast, and it's possible some of them may be removed. Here's the transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" exclude-result-prefixes="" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/comp">
        <comp>
            <xsl:for-each select="./fig">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="major">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(./@xml:id,'-'),'c')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="minor">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(./@xml:id,'fig-'))"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="resume_offset">
                    <xsl:if test="./@resumeatnum">
                        <xsl:value-of select="number(./@resumeatnum - $minor)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="not(./@resumeatnum)">
                        <xsl:if test="./preceding-sibling::*[@resumeatnum]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="number(./preceding-sibling::*[@resumeatnum][1]/@resumeatnum) - number(substring-after(./preceding-sibling::*[@resumeatnum][1]/@xml:id,'fig-'))"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="not(./preceding-sibling::*[@resumeatnum])">
                            <xsl:value-of select="number(0)"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:variable>
                <fignum>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$major"/>
                    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$minor+$resume_offset"/>
                </fignum>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </comp>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```